# Is it good practice to store model object inside table view cell?

Tags: ios

Let's say that my table view has a list of movies.

Each cell has a button to add it to favorites.

Is it good practice to store the movie object inside the table view cell so that on the button press, the object's proprty `isFavorite` would be set to true? This way a reference would be held to the movie in the table view's data source. Is this a good practice?

Another way would be to use a delegate inside the table view cell, but this would mean storing the indexPath of the movie in the cell.

Is the first version good enough? Thanks.

Comment: You don't need to store the `indexPath` in the cell; The cell should pass it`self` to the delegate method and then you can use `indexPath(for: UITableViewCell)` to get the indexpath.  If you update your model in multiple places then your app becomes more complex and there is greater chance for bugs.

Answer (score 1):

Short Answer - NO.

View should be as dumb as it can be, you should not add business logic in view.

You should use delegation approach -

If using MVC - you can have the delegate method in controller extension, and it should call model object to save it.

If using MVVM - then view model should take that responsibility

This is one good [tutorial](http://iyadagha.com/using-mvp-ios-swift/) where you can see how you can make your UI dumb.

Comment: Thanks. Can you also explain me WHY it isn't a good practice? I still think that it eases the flow considerably.

Comment: WHY -> Design principles. View should not be responsible for handling any logic, if you handle logic in view that defies the whole logic behind any architecture pattern you are following. View should always be designed in a manner they can be easily reusable, if you keep the logic inside view, there will be no reusability.